# Converting from InnoDB tables to innodb_file_per_table

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I run MySQL and I have 7 schemas, 6 of the 7 schemas are MyISAM.

In one of my schemas I have 20 tables that are InnoDB, the rest are MyISAM.

I really want to convert those 20 tables over to file_per_table.

I read some old documentation on how to do this, but I'm wondering if this approach will work.

1. Export the foreign keys off the 20 tables.
2. Drop the foreign keys.
3. Convert the tables to MyISAM.
4. Stop MySQL.
5. Change the *my.cnf/ini* to put MySQL in *innodb_file_per_table* mode.
6. Delete the *idbdata* files.
7. Start MySQL.
8. Switch those tables back to InnoDB (which should be in file mode now).
9. Re-apply the foreign keys.

Am I missing any steps? Or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: if you are using MySQL 5.6.6 or higher then  `innodb_file_per_table` is enabled by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process you mentioned works fine but it takes much amount of time if the tables are bigger  in size 
Here the way you can do it quickly .but it requires some down time depends on the table size .

1. Take the full backup of 20 tables that are InnoDB.
2. Drop those 20  tables that are InnoDB
3. Stop mysql
4. Delete the ibdata files
5. Start the mysql services with  innodb_file_per_table=1 in my.cnf
6. Restore those 20  tables that are InnoDB with taken backup.

Comment: With MyISAM tables, I can delete the ibdata1 and I still have the data. If I put the database in innodb_file_per_table then delete the ibdata1 (I lose all the data in my innodb_per_file tables. So their is still a reliance on ibdata for innodb - even in per file table mode.

Comment: You _must_ dump _all_ innodb tables before deleting `ibdata1`.  (And reload.)

Comment: Even file_per_table tables have some info in ibdata1.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the mysql services with innodb_file_per_table=on in my.cnf and rename table to another database and again to original data base then it will create file per table option

Comment: Only 1 step is necessary.  And it does not shrink ibdata1.